# ASP MVC 5 - Remove Child Entities From Parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can I remove All child entities from a one to many relationship via the parent - Note I only want to remove the children.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a shorthand way, lets say something like below:

```
 parent.children.Remove();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your mechanism for deleting the child elements in EF 4 and above should be:

```
parent.children.ToList().ForEach(c => context.Children.Remove(c));
context.SaveChanges();
```

I have found in the past that it *may* be faster to write a `DELETE` yourself, but you should decide what is best for you. Introducing a SQL `DELETE` in an Entity Framework solution adds some complexity both to testing and because your `DELETE` will depend on things you may have been trying to avoid as EF takes care of it all. Always measure before you optimize and decide what trade-offs work for you.

Comment: how do i remove it with Delete? I get error `DbSet does not contain a definition for delete`

Comment: @adam78 - they deprecated that method... who knew! (although it is still on ObjectContext) so example updated.